# Calling child function from parent. Function is not publicly visible after even adding the reference

Tags: flutter

I want to call this function `addPresetToList()` from a different `parent widget`. I have imported the `AnimatedListWidget` (Child widget) to the `parent widget`. But still the function is not visible and publicly available. What could be the issue? and `what are the other ways` to call the functions which is inside an another class? I can't separate the `function` into a different `class` and `call it` as it requires to aqqire data eg: `_selectedItem` etc.

```
void addPresetToList() {
    final int index =
        _selectedItem == null ? _list.length : _list.indexOf(_selectedItem!);
    _list.insert(index, _nextItem++);
  }
```

**This is the full code of the list widget which contains the above code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// void main() {
//   runApp(const AnimatedListSample());
// }

class AnimatedListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedListWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnimatedListWidget> createState() => _AnimatedListWidgetState();
}

class _AnimatedListWidgetState extends State<AnimatedListWidget> {
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  late ListModel<int> _list;
  int? _selectedItem;
  late int
      _nextItem; // The next item inserted when the user presses the '+' button.

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _list = ListModel<int>(
      listKey: _listKey,
      initialItems: <int>[0, 1, 2],
      removedItemBuilder: _buildRemovedItem,
    );
    _nextItem = 3;
  }

  // Used to build list items that haven't been removed.
  Widget _buildItem(
      BuildContext context, int index, Animation<double> animation) {
    return CardItem(
      animation: animation,
      item: _list[index],
      selected: _selectedItem == _list[index],
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _selectedItem = _selectedItem == _list[index] ? null : _list[index];
        });
      },
    );
  }
 
  Widget _buildRemovedItem(
      int item, BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation) {
    return CardItem(
      animation: animation,
      item: item,
      // No gesture detector here: we don't want removed items to be interactive.
    );
  }

// class AddRemoveListItems {
  // Insert the "next item" into the list model.
  void addPresetToList() {
    final int index =
        _selectedItem == null ? _list.length : _list.indexOf(_selectedItem!);
    _list.insert(index, _nextItem++);
  }

  // Remove the selected item from the list model.
  void remove() {
    if (_selectedItem != null) {
      _list.removeAt(_list.indexOf(_selectedItem!));
      setState(() {
        _selectedItem = null;
      });
    }
  }

// }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            //child: Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Expanded(
              child: AnimatedList(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                key: _listKey,
                initialItemCount: _list.length,
                itemBuilder: _buildItem,
              ),
            ))));
  }
}

 

typedef RemovedItemBuilder<T> = Widget Function(
    T item, BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation);

 
class ListModel<E> {
  ListModel({
    required this.listKey,
    required this.removedItemBuilder,
    Iterable<E>? initialItems,
  }) : _items = List<E>.from(initialItems ?? <E>[]);

  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey;
  final RemovedItemBuilder<E> removedItemBuilder;
  final List<E> _items;

  AnimatedListState? get _animatedList => listKey.currentState;

  void insert(int index, E item) {
    _items.insert(index, item);
    _animatedList!.insertItem(index);
  }

  E removeAt(int index) {
    final E removedItem = _items.removeAt(index);
    if (removedItem != null) {
      _animatedList!.removeItem(
        index,
        (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation) {
          return removedItemBuilder(removedItem, context, animation);
        },
      );
    }
    return removedItem;
  }

  int get length => _items.length;

  E operator [](int index) => _items[index];

  int indexOf(E item) => _items.indexOf(item);
}

 
class CardItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardItem({
    Key? key,
    this.onTap,
    this.selected = false,
    required this.animation,
    required this.item,
  })  : assert(item >= 0),
        super(key: key);

  final Animation<double> animation;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  final int item;
  final bool selected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4!;
    if (selected) {
      textStyle = textStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[400]);
    }
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: SizeTransition(
        sizeFactor: animation,
        child: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: onTap,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 80.0,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.primaries[item % Colors.primaries.length],
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Item $item', style: textStyle),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it is usually impossible (or not good practice) to call a function from a parent widget, usually, all communication between parent and child looks like this:

```
+--------+             +-------+
| parent | ---data---> | child |
|        | <-callback- |       |
+--------+             +-------+
```

In your case, that probably means that both `_list` and `_selectedItem` must be part of your parent widget and sent over as data for the child widget to use.

```
class AnimatedListWidget extends StatelessWidget 
{
  AnimatedListWidget({this.selectedItem, required this.list, required this.listKey, required this.changeSelected});

  final int? selectedItem;
  final ListModel<int> list;
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey;
  final ValueChanged<int>? changeSelected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Expanded(
              child: AnimatedList(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                key: _listKey,
                initialItemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: _buildItem,
              ),
            ))));
  }
    Widget _buildItem(
      BuildContext context, int index, Animation<double> animation) {
    return CardItem(
      animation: animation,
      item: list[index],
      selected: selectedItem == list[index],
      onTap: changeSelected==null?null : () => changeSelected(index);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then on the parent widget:

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {

  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  late ListModel<int> _list;
  int? _selectedItem;
  late int
      _nextItem; // The next item inserted when the user presses the '+' button.

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _list = ListModel<int>(
      listKey: _listKey,
      initialItems: <int>[0, 1, 2],
      removedItemBuilder: _buildRemovedItem,
    );
    _nextItem = 3;
  }

  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedListWidget(
      selectedItem = _selectedItem,
      list: _list,
      listKey: _listKey,
      changeSelected: (i) => setState(() =>_selectedItem = _selectedItem == _list[i] ? null : _list[i]),
    );
  }

  void addPresetToList() {
    final int index =
        _selectedItem == null ? _list.length : _list.indexOf(_selectedItem!);
    _list.insert(index, _nextItem++);
    setState(() {});
  }

}
```

This way the parent **can** access the function because it is part of the parent. If you want the child to access it, you have to pass it as a callback like you would on an `onPressed` method on an elevated button

Comment: it has a lot of issues errors, one of them is `ListModel` is not defined, and when I define it in the child, it gives more endless errors. Are you sure the code is complete?

Comment: no, it was not meant to be complete, it was just an example of how it should work, I think you should define `ListModel` on `list_model.dart` and import it into both files? maybe that solves the error?